# error ODBC Text driver Undefined function 'PATINDEX' in expression

Tags: c#, sql

I try to export .csv file to sql server using **ODBC** driver

my code is

```
condition += "left(SYMBOL,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SYMBOL)-1) ='" + rdr["Company"].ToString().ToUpper() + "') ";
```

But I got the error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] undefined function 'PATINDEX'

Comment: Can you provide your error also

Comment: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] undefined function 'PATINDEX' in expression